# Pivot Task Name, Start and End Date records in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

My data looks like as follows:

```
TASK_NAME      START_DATE           END_DATE
--------------------------------------------
TASK1          01-Jan-2010       31-Mar-2010
TASK2          01-Apr-2010       01-Jul-2010
TASK3          01-Sep-2011       01-Nov-2011
```

I'd like to run a SQL in Oracle 11g that will output the data as follows

```
TASKNAME1           START1             END1          TASKNAME2    START1            END1
TASK1            01-Jan-2010       31-Mar-2010        TASK2      01-Apr-2010       01-Jul-2010
```

and so on, can this be done using pure 11g SQL? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious to know a good use case for something like that. Can you elaborate a bit on what you want to do?

Comment: Can the list of `tasks` grow endlessly?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback typically the list will only show 3 years worth of data.

Comment: I believe you can't have a *variable* number of columns when you `PIVOT`.  You can *kinda* simulate PIVOT output with `LISTAGG`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your actual requirement, but to output of your sample:

```
   START1             END1          TASKNAME2    START1            END1
TASK1            01-Jan-2010       31-Mar-2010        TASK2      01-Apr-2010       01-Jul-2010
```

-

This is my try: (my practice atleast) :), may be you could use a part of this:

```
    SELECT A.task1 taskname1, A.start_date start1, A.end_date end1, b.task2 taskname2, b.start_date start2, b.end_date end2 
FROM
         (SELECT task1, start_date, end_date
         FROM
              ( SELECT task_name, start_date , end_date FROM my_table8
              ) pivot(MAX(task_name) FOR task_name IN ('TASK1' task1,'TASK2' task2,'TASK3' task3))
    WHERE task1 IS NOT NULL)A,
    (SELECT task2, start_date, end_date
         FROM
              ( SELECT task_name, start_date , end_date FROM my_table8
              ) pivot(MAX(task_name) FOR task_name IN ('TASK1' task1,'TASK2' task2,'TASK3' task3))
    WHERE task2 IS NOT NULL)b;
```